# React Native Firebase v9 Creating weird errors on configuration

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React Native, firebase auth, firestore, and expo.

```
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^16.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
```

Creating this error:

> TypeError: (0, _app.initializeApp) is not a function. (In '(0, _app.initializeApp)(firebaseConfig)', '(0, _app.initializeApp)' is undefined)

Which is leading me to believe something is wrong in my firebase config.

Originally, I tried using "firebase": "^8.2.3" because all the tutorials I watched where mostly in the old version of firebase - so I did and everything worked
This was my config file:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
   //redacted info
};

let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = firebase.app()
}

const auth = firebase.auth()

export { auth };
```

And then I wanted to use firestore, and the conflicting package versions was creating issues for me, so I updated all packages to the newest version -

```
"firebase": "^9.15.0"
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^16.5.0",
```

And updated my config file to the new syntax:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    //redacted
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth();
```

I am recieving this error:

> TypeError: (0, _app.initializeApp) is not a function. (In '(0, _app.initializeApp)(firebaseConfig)', '(0, _app.initializeApp)' is undefined)

I have tried different ways of importing firebase - no luck

'npm list' yielded:

```
+-- @react-native-firebase/firestore@16.5.0 
+-- @react-native-firebase/storage@16.5.0 
+-- firebase@8.2.3 invalid: "^9.15.0" from the root project
```

What is interesting is that tons of errors show all saying:
invalid: "~XYZ" from the root project

From there, I tried deleting package-lock.json and than running npm install, and more errors appeared:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: awesomeproject@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/native@6.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/native@"^6.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"18.1.0" from react-native@0.70.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.70.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-navigation/native@6.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/native@"^6.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"` as per [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize)?

Comment: Looks like you should also consult the [React Native Firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/)

Comment: hi phil, thanks for looking at it but I believe I do actually import using `import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';`, check out the bottom half of my question

Comment: The fact that it's showing the exact same error leads me to believe you haven't actually built the changes

Comment: Interesting, but the error started appearing *after* I changed the file to match the new syntax, so the error was never there before. It was working perfectly fine. Is there another way to build changes rather than just running on the expo?

Comment: Right, I misunderstood since you repeated the error message. Have you actually installed the latest version? If you only updated `package.json`, you also need to run `npm install`

Comment: Hi Phil, I ran npm list and got a bunch of errors, but the actual versions seem to be off as well for firebase. For some reason formatting is not working here, please check the bottom of my question to see what I mean about the errors.

Comment: Phil, I fixed it by forcing the npm install. I think my packages were not truly installed. 
``npm install --force ``
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my packages were not truly installed. We see this from all the errors when running npm install, and also when

```
'npm list' shows errors like:
+-- firebase@8.2.3 invalid: "^9.15.0" from the root project
```

showed me that this package might not actually be the version I want.

Fixed using:

```
npm install --force
```

Thanks, everyone!